# End user platform for Twilio Studio?

Tags: user-interface, twilio

Is there a UI component to allow back and forth messaging using Twilio Studio? Sort of like the OpenVBX app was? A way to initiate calls and texts from a Twilio number without integrating into an existing system like a CRM?

I'm working with a small local campaign and want to have a way for a few volunteers to login somewhere and respond to messages, calls, and voicemails using the campaign numbers. I know OpenVBX accomplishes this, and I can stand up an instance of that, but was wondering if there was a newer better mechanism with Studio since OpenVBX is all but abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Jarod from Twilio here. Studio is a great place to define an automated interaction, but for organizing volunteers I would suggest looking at The Rapid Response Kit by Twilio. This allows volunteers to login and respond to messages and calls.

- The Code: https://github.com/Twilio-org/rapid-response-kit
- Blog Post to get started: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/12/non-coders-guide-running-twilio-org-rapid-response-kit.html

Hope this helps!